# Understanding Keras LSTM model with varying size of batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a working LSTM model with Keras, but I need more control over things so I'm transforming to tensorflow (1.13).

In the way of doing so, first thing I encountered was the batch size handling.

This is the Keras' simple model:

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(seq_length, X_train.shape[2]),return_sequences=False))
model1.add(Dense(y_train.shape[2], activation='softmax'))
model1.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# y_train[:,-1,:] takes only the fifth timestap's y of each sample
model1.fit(X_train, y_train[:,-1,:], epochs=300, batch_size=512)
```

I'm using `batch_size` of 512 for example, while the number of samples in `X_train` is 108765, a number that can't be divided (fully) by 512, which means that the last epoch's last step will be 221 instead of 512. 
Keras handles this in the back and I didn't need to do anything for it.
When using TensorFlow, I need to specify a batch size for the initial state - which will be used throughout the epoch as the output state of `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`.

So:

1. How does Keras handle this?
2. What can be done in TensorFlow order to overcome this, without losing data to fit the batch size?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit complicated to go over everything, but let's start with how can you do this with Tensorflow. So, firstly same constants:

```
# Input data
X = np.random.rand(108765, 10, 3).astype(np.float32)
# The number of epochs
epochs = 10
# The size of the batch, in your case 512
batch_size = 512
# Size of the cell, 64 as per your code
cell_size = 64
```

Now, the data loading logic. We can create a `tf.data.Dataset()`, that will take care of the loading of the data automatically:

```
# A dataset from a tensor
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X)
# Shuffle the dataset with some arbitrary buffer size
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10)
# Divide the dataset into batches. Once you reach the last batch which won't be 512, the dataset will know exactly which elements remain and should be passed as a batch.
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
# An iterator that can be reinitialized over and over again, therefore having a new shuffle of the data each time
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
# A node that can be run to obtain the next element in the dataset. However, this node will be linked in the model so obtaining the next element will be done automatically
data_X = iterator.get_next()
```

The final part of the model is the `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` itself:

```
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(cell_size)
current_batch_size = tf.shape(data_X)[0]
init_state = cell.zero_state(current_batch_size, tf.float32)
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=data_X, initial_state=init_state)
```

Now, we are set to create the training logic:

```
# Creation of a session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initialization of all variables in the TF graph
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # Executing the block below epoch times
    for e in range(epochs):
        # Each time, reinitialize the iterator to obtain a fresh shuffle of the training data
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
        try:
            # As long as there are elements execute the block below
            while True:
               # The whole training logic
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            pass
```

I assume that this code should help you to assemble your own logic to create a TF model and train it. As for how `keras` does things in the background, I don't know exactly. Similarly as TF, let's assume that it knows which elements have passed, and which elements remain in the data loading module.

Finally, I want to point out that all these things are complicated for themselves and you should do a bit of reading on your own. In particular, the purpose of the answer is to help you understand how can you do the data loading without loosing any information. Good luck!

Comment: I will use `tf.data.Dataset()`,didn't know that before.But I still have the batch size problem: `dynamic_rnn` needs to get init_state with the shape `[NUM_LAYERS, 2, TRAIN_BATCHES, HIDDEN_SIZE]` since it's gonna be a tuple,`tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss` needs the shape in two places -the `logits` needs to be of shape `[batch_size, seq_len, output_size]` and the weights which are `tf.ones([batch_size, self.seq_len], dtype=tf.float32)` in my case. In all these places I have to specify a batch size when creating the graph, so how can I change it for the last batch (it can't be a placeholder)?

Comment: You can obtain the current batch size dynamically. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: This might work! I'll try and update. Is it possible to do another trick without using `tf.data.Dataset()` ? I wanted to use placeholders for input since I might need to do some generation tasks (like text-generation) later and a placeholder will be able to get `None` as the sequence length (as the sequence will increment with each generation)

Comment: Sure that you can. However, the whole batching process you will have to do manually which slows down everything and you can't use prefetching (Assuming that you train on GPU).

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of RNN in Keras:

- `stateful=True`
- `stateful=False` (your case according to the code you posted)

The difference between them is that the `True` version will keep the states in memory between batches (to simulate that the second batch is a sequel of the first batch, for instance), while the `False` version will create a new state matrix for every batch (so every batch contains full sequences, not parts of sequences).

So, in the `True` case, Keras does face the same problem as you do: it needs a fixed batch size, and in fact it demands that you specify the batch size when you use `stateful=True`.

But, if you're using `stateful=False`, it will just create a new states matrix full of zeros.

So, basically:

- If you want to create a Tensorflow `stateful=True` layer, you need the batch size to be constant, just as Keras also does
- If you want to create a Tensorflow `stateful=False` layer, you can just create new states as an all-zeros matrix with shape `(samples, output_dim)`

Comment: That's true, I need it as `stateful=False` , and I do create an all-zero matrix: `current_state = np.zeros((NUM_LAYERS, 2, cur_batch_size, HIDDEN_SIZE))` that is passed to a placeholder `init_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [NUM_LAYERS, 2, self.batch_size, HIDDEN_SIZE],name='init_state')` and used in the `dynamic_rnn` later (after making a tuple). The `init_state` placeholder needs to know the batch_size upfront (I tried passing as a placeholder,which fails) - how can I overcome this ?

Comment: Why a placeholder? It's not data you're going to feed, but plain zeros as results of calculation. And although I'm not really into Tensorflow, it seems quite clear that it accepts variable size placeholders (otherwise Keras wouldn't be able to pass variable size batches). Isn't it a case of passing `-1` or `?` to that dimension?

Comment: A placeholder for cases when I get the new state and pass it again as the next state (`stateless=True`) . And no, placeholder can't get `-1` instead of batch size (tried it). But even if it's not a placeholder, I will still have to create it with a certain size - a size that will be fixed once I create the graph (if it's not a placeholder).

Comment: I'm quite sure it can accept a variable size, Keras is built with placeholders and it does accept a lot of variable inputs.

Comment: Internet examples use `None` (just as Keras)